# How to write a PHP code to execute a CRON job?

Tags: php, cron

I have a database where uploaded music details are stored.

In my database I have `location` of music stored

Data of Table is like this:

```
TableA

id      musicpath                status

1      /X/Y/Z/abc.mp3             1
2      /X/Y/Z/abc1.mp3            0
3      /X/Y/Z/abc3.p3             1
4      /X/Y/Z/abc5mp3             1
```

In the above table, id is `auto-increment`, and `musicpath` is the location where music is stored.  If the status of any row is 1, cron will run and compress the uploaded music and replace the existing file and the status will be updated to 0. I have ffmpeg installed and I can compress using ssh but through PHP I tried but its not working so i have decided to write `CRON`

cron will execute this code for compressing but other details if any one can share it wil be a great help.

```
exec('ffmpeg -y -i ' . $_FILES['song']['name'] . ' -ab 24000 ' . $_FILES['song']['name'] . '');
```

i know how to setup cron to execute the php file . but i dont know how to write php file which will be executed by cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add a shebang line to your PHP script and make it executable (`chmod +x`):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// your code
```

Then you can use it in the crontab like any other script/program, i.e. `/path/to/whatever.php`.

Comment: He says he knows how to set up a cron to execute a php file.

Comment: "but i dont know how to write php file which will be executed by cron" sounded like he doesn't know what to put in the php file so cron can execute it.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a file you need to access from the webserver too, you can simply run it with php.

```
/usr/bin/php5 /path/to/your/script.php
```

The path to php5 can change you can find it by runing

```
whereis php5
```